# Cartthrob abandoned carts for non-logged in users

Tags: cartthrob

Has anyone been able to get the Cartthrob abandoned cart plugin to work for "guest" shoppers (i.e. they aren't logged in with an account)?

The checkout process is a single form to enter address details which then goes to an offsite payment gateway. I was hoping that once the address details were completed the user's email would be logged against their cart.

I thought that the plugin would do this out of the box but it doesn't appear to be the case. It will only store the email address if the user is logged in (the abandoned cart email function worked perfectly in this case).

Am I just doing something wrong, is this a bug, or is it just something that the plugin doesn't do?

I've also tried creating an account on checkout but this doesn't seem to happen until after the checkout process is complete.

The documentation isn't amazing and doesn't really clarify how the plugin **should** work. However it **does** mention guest checkouts which indicates that this should work as I expected. Do I have unrealistic expectations of this $500 plugin!

I have a support request in with Cartthrob/Vector but haven't heard anything back yet and I'm keen to try and resolve the issue one way or the other.

UPDATE
I've hacked around this problem for now by modifying Cartthrob's checkout method to add the customer's email address to the cart when they checkout.

It looks like the plugin only adds the email when the add to cart method is called. So obviously if they haven't entered an email at that time it will never work.

If the behaviour could be triggered on other actions that would make it much easier to log the email address and make this plugin more useful.

Comment: Hi Pete! It sounds like you may have figured out the intended behavior but I'm going to respond to your support request now with more.